# Reactive Cocoa: Response from HTTPRequest using RACCommand

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I'm completely new to the Reactive Cocoa Framework and i'm just doing some simple tests but i'm encountering a problem that i would like to understand.

Basically i'm just doing an API call to fetch a JSON object from my server, i want to do this with RAC. So my steps are the following:

**First i build the RACCommand this way:**

```
RACCommand *getLatestVersionCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    return [[[API sharedInstance] getLatestAppVersion]
                materialize];
}];
```

**Now i create the signal and subscribe to it this way:**

```
RACSignal *versionCodeSignal = [[getLatestVersionCommand.executionSignals flatten] deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];
[[versionCodeSignal
    map:^id(NSDictionary *responseObject) {
        return responseObject;
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(NSDictionary *responseObject) {
        NSArray *allVersions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[responseObject objectForKey:KEY_VERSIONS]];
        for(NSDictionary *version in allVersions) {
            NSString *device = [version objectForKey:KEY_DEVICE];
            if([device isEqualToString:KEY_IOS]) {
                NSString *latestVersionName = [[version objectForKey:KEY_VERSION] objectForKey:KEY_NAME];
                if([APP_VERSION compare:latestVersionName options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending) {
                    //There is a new version!
                    NSLog(@"There is a new version!!!");
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

**Finally I execute the command this way**

```
[getLatestVersionCommand execute:self];
```

The problem i'm facing is that in the subscribeNext block, the object i receive is an RACEvent object and not the dictionary i'm expecting. I know i'm doing something wrong and not understanding the full flow correctly, i tried adding the map function that i thought i didn't need just to test and nothing.

The only way i found is to convert the response in the map block to a RACEvent and return its value but that doesn't seem to me the right way to go.

Any light will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the call to `-[RACSignal materialize]` from your command's signal block.

Comment: It works! Could you explain what's the main difference? Just to understand the framework better.

Comment: BTW I also removed the unecesary map block

Comment: Signals can generate three different kinds of events: values (sometimes called "nexts"), completes, and errors. If a signal sends either a complete or an error, the subscription is terminated immediately, and there can never be another value/complete/error sent on that subscription. The `-materialize` method converts all nexts, completes, and errors into a special kind of value (a RACEvent). This lets you use operations that only work on values even on non-value events (think `-map:` or `-filter:`). `-materialize/dematerialize` are useful in rare cases, but not widely used.